# Shortcut to move up and down in the suggestion list provided by the visual studio 2019 intellisense

Tags: visual-studio, intellisense

Can anyone plz tell what are the shortcuts to move up and down in suggestion list visual studio intellisense.

For example in visual studio code (CTRL + n) lets us go down list and (CTRL + p) lets us go up in the suggestion.

Comment: Do you mean the intellisense offered when there are multiple overrides of a function listed as _1 of n_, _2 of n_, etc.?

Comment: isn't it just the arrow keys?

Comment: NO. OBVIOUSLY ARROW KEYS WORK. BUT ITS NOT CONVINIENT UNLIKE <CTRL> + p AND <CTRL> + n , LIKE IN VS CODE

Answer (score 1):

We can use user keybindings to navigate up and down in suggestions available.

There are two default key bindings selectPrevSuggestion and selectNextSuggestion in vscode which can be used to move up and down in the suggestions list.

First, we have to got to show default key bindings from settings and here, we can change **selectPrevSuggestion** and **selectNextSuggestion** easily as our wish.

In below screenshot we can see that enter image description here
[image]
For selectPrevSuggestion it is upArrow by default which can be changed by clicking on it easily to our wish.

Similary, we can change for selectNextSuggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there are not related shortcuts like vscode in visual studio. If you want it in future version, you can provide a new feature here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=8&entry=suggestion

Comment: Sure I will do that. Thanks for sharing the link.